# Update a specific scope from collection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've a collection of messages, like this:

```
$scope.messages = [];
myMsgService.getAll().then(function (messages) {
     $scope.messages.push(messages);//array of objects - this is my collection    
});
```

My html:

```
  <div data-ng-controller="MessageController" data-ng-repeat="message in messages" class="message">...</div>
```

I've 10 messages, if i want to update just one message(in my html) after has updated it in my database, how i would do that? Imagine that i click in one message, edit it, update in my database and after this i just want to update this single message in my html, how i would do that?

Comment: Just curious, does the code you posted actually work? I can see several mistakes with it. Or is it intended to be pseudo code ?

Comment: i don't know, because i just wrote this to use in my example... But can you say to me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Okay so when you click on the message on your html you have an index of it inside the array like ng-click="doThisAfterClick($index)", then all you need to do is access the $scope.messages[index] = {} <-- new value. on your data-ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index" to get the index and use it on your ng-click function. Is that what you want?

Comment: Basically loop through the array using the ng-repeat adding a track by $index and use that index to be passed on your ng-click="yourFunction($index)" and on your controller you have your yourFunction($index) { // your logic inside }.

Comment: Soto, my problem is not find, i find it inside my $scope.messages collection(by id, using lo-dash, 'where' function), my problem is to manipulate it, and when manipulate it, it reflect in my html...

Answer (score 1):

Just created a fiddle, if this helps

```
angular.module('myapp',[])
  .controller('MessageController',function($scope){
     $scope.messages=['one','two','three','four','five'];
      $scope.valChange=function(index,msg){
       //just for test. logic to store in db
        $scope.messages[index]=msg;
        console.log($scope.messages);
      }
  });
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/S2UFK/1/)